# Replace "?" with "Ñ" in bigquery table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to perform an update in 21 rows. The way I came up with is using a query to get the new values and the id where to update the table. However, I'm getting `UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row`.

The data looks like this:

```
new_address      address              id        
ÑANDU 123       ?ANDU 123            17-18
OTOÑAL 12       OTO?AL 12            10-16
```

The query I'm using looks like this:

```
UPDATE table 
SET direccion = new_address 
FROM (SELECT new_address FROM(SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(address,r'\?',"Ñ") AS new_address,address,id
FROM table) WHERE address LIKE "%?%")
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM (SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(address,r'\?',"Ñ") AS new_address,address,id
FROM table) WHERE address LIKE "%?%")
```

Why is this error and how can I achieve this?

Comment: It looks like you treated that address as ASCII somewhere along the line, which caused that ñ to be replaced by a ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "join condition" in the `WHERE` clause (e.g. on the id column) to say which value generated by the `FROM` clause applies to a given target row.

But in this case you don't need a "joined update"; a simpler "searched update" would do:

```
UPDATE table 
SET address = REGEXP_REPLACE(address,r'\?',"Ñ") 
WHERE address LIKE "%?%"
```

If you did want to use joined update it would look something like:

```
UPDATE table 
SET address = new_address 
FROM (SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(address,r'\?',"Ñ") AS new_address, id as upd_id
  FROM table WHERE address LIKE "%?%")
WHERE id=upd_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are trying some heavy workaround instead of just going as simple as below

```
UPDATE table 
SET address = REGEXP_REPLACE(address, r'\?', "Ñ")
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(address, r'\?')
```

Comment: did you have chance to try?